JWT token expires immediately after it's being generated
i want to apply JWT in my app login system, when user logs in the server generate JWT token with an expiration period of 30 minutes, then the server does some token validation through a tokenMiddleware, it checks if the request header has an Authorization header with a value that starts with Bearer, then if the token exists the middleware graps and verifies the token, for now i decided to test my code so i requested POST /login with some registered user and password, then the login method sent me back a user data object with the token as intended, so i've used this middleware for route GET /team with the Authorization and the correct token value, now i expect the middleware to console log a decoded object contains id, iat and exp payload, but the server breaks and it says TokenExpiredError: jwt expired
controller.jsx
  login: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
       ...validate user

      // generate token when user logs in
      const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRY,
      });

      // send user data and token
      res.json({
        status: 200,
        loggedInUser: loggedInUser,
        accessToken: token,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  },

  getTeam: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      // grap users from database
      const [teamUsers] = await DB.execute(
        "SELECT id,fullname, position, image FROM team"
      );
      // send users
      res.status(201).json({
        teamUsers: teamUsers,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  },

tokenMiddleware.js
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import { promisify } from "util";
export default async function protect(req, res, next) {
  let token;

  // check if request header contains authorization header and that the value starts with Bearer, if so then gets the token
  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer")
  ) {
    token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
  }

  // if token doesn't exist, then send response to inform that user is not logged in and need to log in to get access
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      message: "You are not logged in! Please log in to get access.",
    });
  }

  // if token exist then verify the token using the access token secret key
  const decode = promisify(jwt.verify)(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
  console.log(decode);

  next();

}


.env
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=...
ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRY=1800 (1800 seconds, 30 minutes)

routes.js
import protect from "./tokenMiddleware.js";

routes.post("/login", controller.login);

// apply token middleware to protect this route
routes.get("/team", protect, controller.getTeam);



Make sure you have dotenv correctly installed and also this (1800 seconds, 30 minutes) is not in a comment (unless you dont have it in your real .env)

Expiration time defaults to milliseconds if you pass the number as a string (and you do, all env variables are strings.) 1800 ms = 1.8 seconds

@thecodingsage i've just put it here to explain, im also sure dotenv is currently installed and used, thanks for your comment tho

@GuyIncognito Expiration time defaults to milliseconds - reference?  expiresIn: expressed in seconds or a string describing a time span as described in https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken?tab=readme-ov-file#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback

@jps They're using the jsonwebtoken npm package: "If you use a string be sure you provide the time units (days, hours, etc), otherwise milliseconds unit is used by default ("120" is equal to "120ms")."
